# OpenApi Cdiscount GetProduct does not work with EAN

Tags: python, openapi

The below python code should return information about a product on Cdiscount.com like price, URL etc...

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.cdiscount.com/OpenApi/json/GetProduct'
payload = {
  "ApiKey": "MY_KEY",
  "ProductRequest": {
    "EANList": [
      "3168430717046"
    ],
    "Scope": {
      "Offers": False,
      "AssociatedProducts": False,
      "Images": False,
      "Ean": True
    }
  }
}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

But the result is just:

```
{
  "Products": null
}
```

I tried other EAN codes but the result is always the same. I know that these EAN codes exist on Cdiscount. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I wanted to add the tag [cdiscount] but couldn't. Maybe someone else can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I asked CDiscount support for help and they gave me the solution : just set the "AssociatedProducts" parameter to "true" and it will work ;)

Exemple :

```
{

  "ApiKey": "YOURKEY",

  "ProductRequest": {

    "ProductEANList": [

      "0888462479127"

    ],

    "Scope": {

      "Offers": false,

      "AssociatedProducts": true,

      "Images": false,

      "Ean": false

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. Maybe someone could add the tag "cdiscount" so that an "Cdiscount" employee could have a look.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work ? I played with all parameters but it seems it does not work.